# postgres - calculating cumulative sum based on conditions

Tags: postgresql, grouping, cumulative-sum

I have a DB table called `asset_reporting` which looks like this

```
asset_id      asset_type       entered_at             exited_at         site_id
  100           Cage       2019-05-02 10:00:00    2019-05-04 10:00:00     25
  102           Cage       2019-05-03 10:00:00         null               25
  103         Container    2019-05-01 10:00:00    2019-05-03 10:00:00     25
```

I need to calculate the running total of how long an asset has been at a particular site within a given time range. Assuming the time range I'm looking at is from 2019-05-01 to 2019-05-05, the output I need is below day-wise

```
     day       asset_type        count
 2019-05-01      Cage              0
 2019-05-01    Container           1
 2019-05-02      Cage              1
 2019-05-02    Container           1
 2019-05-03      Cage              2
 2019-05-03    Container           1
 2019-05-04      Cage              2
 2019-05-04    Container           0
 2019-05-05      Cage              1
 2019-05-05    Container           0
```

I have the got the query below so far. I'm unable to figure out how to keep a running total of the total number of days an asset was at a site

```
select date(ar.entered_at) as day, asset_type, count(*) from asset_reporting ar
group by day,asset_type
```

And below is the output with the above query. Notice it doesn't my expected output above.

```
     day       asset_type        count
 2019-05-01      Cage              0
 2019-05-01    Container           1
 2019-05-02      Cage              1
 2019-05-02    Container           0
 2019-05-03      Cage              1
 2019-05-03    Container           0
 2019-05-04      Cage              0
 2019-05-04    Container           0
 2019-05-05      Cage              0
 2019-05-05    Container           0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this using a calendar table approach:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '2019-05-01'::date AS day UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-05-02'::date UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-05-03'::date UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-05-04'::date UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-05-05'::date
)

SELECT
    d.day,
    at.asset_type,
    COUNT(ar.asset_type) AS count
FROM dates d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT asset_type FROM asset_reporting) at
LEFT JOIN asset_reporting ar
    ON at.asset_type = ar.asset_type AND
       (d.day >= ar.entered_at::date OR ar.entered_at IS NULL) AND
       (d.day <= ar.exited_at::date OR ar.exited_at IS NULL)
GROUP BY
    d.day,
    at.asset_type
ORDER BY
    d.day,
    at.asset_type;
```

[image]

### Demo